# select all elements with certain name but without some

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I'm selecting all input elements with name ending Phone like

```
$("input[name$='Phone']")..
```

how can I limit this selection further in a sense that I want to select all input elements with name ending Phone but without element with name `zPhone` and `kkPhone` and `ooo2tPhone` for example.

Comment: `$("input[name$='Phone']").not("input[name^='z']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use not selector:

```
$("input[name$='Phone']").not('[name$="zPhone"]').not('[name$="kkPhone"]')
```

---

But for simplicity I would have names that would end with Phone including an underscore:  `my_Phone, your_Phone, our_Phone, etc.` and then just use:

```
$("input[name$='_Phone']")
```

Comment: You should use `.not('[name$="zPhone"], [name$="kkPhone"]')` or better, use `filter()` because if you need to exclude ten selectors e.g, you would have better to use a regex or whatever

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/not/

```js
$("input[name$='Phone']:not([name='megaPhone'],[name='cellPhone'])").css({border:"2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- YES -->
<input name="mobilePhone">
<input name="telePhone">
<!-- NOT -->
<input name="cellPhone">
<input name="megaPhone">
```

---

Using http://api.jquery.com/filter/ and regex:

```js
$("input[name$='Phone']").filter(function(){
     return !this.name.match(/^(cell|mega)Phone$/);
}).css({border:"2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- YES -->
<input name="mobilePhone">
<input name="telePhone">
<!-- NOT -->
<input name="cellPhone">
<input name="megaPhone">
```

> /^(cell|mega|dicta)Phone$/g
>   ^ assert position at start of the string
>   1st Capturing group (cell|mega|dicta)
>   1st Alternative: cell
>   cell matches the characters cell literally (case sensitive)
>   2nd Alternative: mega
>   mega matches the characters mega literally (case sensitive)
>   3rd Alternative: dicta
>   dicta matches the characters dicta literally (case sensitive)
>   Phone matches the characters Phone literally (case sensitive)
>   $ assert position at end of the string